# 'int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter' with 'selector' creation in Java DSL

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, dsl

I have the such XML bases definition

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
    connection-factory="connectionFactoryName"
    destination="destinationName" channel="channelName" 
    selector="...subscription expression..."
    auto-startup="false"/>
```

and I can create needed adapter in Java DSL like this

```
Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactoryName)
    .destination(destinationName)
    .outputChannel(channelName)
    .autoStartup(false)
    .get();
```

but I can't define here `selector`.

I tried to use `Jms.pollableChannel` factory method but it hasn't ability to define `outputChannel` and `autoStartup` features.

So how I can create `int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter` analog via Java DSL but with needed parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `messageSelector` is a property of `AbstractMessageListenerContainer`.

To be consistent we provide the similar hook to distinguish the responsibility:

```
Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactoryName)
    .destination(destinationName)
    .outputChannel(channelName)
    .autoStartup(false)

    .configureListenerContainer(c -> c.messageSelector("...subscription expression..."))

    .get();
```

Comment: I tried to use another `Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter` method with `listenerContainer` as a parameter but you version is much easier. Thanks!